# Is could please good grammar?

Tags: sentence-construction, collocations

I'm writing a request to a school and I'm trying to politely state my request. However, I can't find the correct phrase to use. I've gone with 'could please' but that doesn't sound right.

Here is the whole sentence:

> I was wondering if I could please retake the test for transition into year 9 and if so, when and where?

Is this right? If not what would be the best phrase to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if I could please retake the test for transition into year 9 and if so, when and where?

Concise sentences are preferred.  My suggestion is

Could I retake the test for transition into year 9?  If so, please let me know the date, time, and place.

Comment: I agree that conciseness is good, but I wouldn't take out both "wondering" and "please", it's perfectly fine to say "Could I please retake..." or "I was wondering if I could retake...".

Comment: @Micah, yes, I agree that your 2 versions are perfectly fine too.  Thx.